# Join with condition

Tags: mysql

I already searched a few solutions on stackoverflow but all of those solutions didn't work for me :/

**First my tables:**

```
game
+----+--------------+
| id | game         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Game1        |
|  2 | Game2        |
|  4 | Game4        |
+----+--------------+

group_game
+---------+----------+
| game_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | 33       |
|       1 | 45       |
|       2 | 33       |
+---------+----------+

groups
+----+------------+----
| id | group_name | ...
+----+------------+----
| 33 | Group33    | ...
| 45 | Group45    | ...
+----+------------+----
```

**The Output**

I have a selectbox with all groups and when the user selects one group there should appear the games which belong to the select group.

For example: I have selected the group with the ID 33 -> $group_id = 33

The output should look like this:

```
- Game1 (ID: 1)
- Game2 (ID: 2)
```

**My code**

```
$sql = $db->prepare("
    SELECT ga.id, ga.game
    FROM game ga 
    LEFT JOIN group_game gg
        ON ga.id = gg.group_id
    WHERE gg.group_id = ?
"); 
$sql->bind_param('i', $group_id);
```

This will display just nothing.

Comment: `bind_param` is used to change a given parameter in the `WHERE` condition in a prepare statment to something else. The problem is that you're trying to change`i` but you haven't declare `i` in your prepared query.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the ?-part and now there is no error. It just displays nothing

Comment: There is `group_game` and `grpup_name`. Surely it is still not correct. Please run the query *in an actual SQL environment* to test for expected results and well-formedness. Also, *check the result of executing a query*. I recommend (using and) enabling PDO *exception throwing* to make this 'hard to forget'.

Comment: I think it will be better to use Procedure in this case where you can put input parameters and get expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sql to join on game_id like so

```
$sql = $db->prepare("
    SELECT ga.id, ga.game
    FROM game ga 
    LEFT JOIN group_game gg
        ON ga.id = gg.game_id
    WHERE gg.group_id = :i
"); 
$sql->bind_param('i', $group_id);
```

The id inside game (ga) is the id found in game_id not group_id.

Also note the :i to bind the named param to a point in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the query could be...

```
SELECT game.*
  FROM group_game 
  JOIN game
    ON game.id = group_game.game_id
 WHERE group_game.group_id = 33;
```

...but that's nothing to do with your error, which is about how you're binding the prepared statement in PHP.